# Why does the layout change in the \titlepage

Tags: titles

I'm trying to put a good format on my front page of my Thesis, but when I put it in my document the layout is not the same as if I run it in a separate document. Some commands get overridden.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}\centering

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the       horizontal lines, change thickness here

\includegraphics[scale=0.85,width=0.90\textwidth]{def.jpg}%

\vspace*{\fill}

\textsc{\Large Trabajo fin de carrera}\\[0.5cm]

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Análisis del efecto de la radiación solar directa sobre el    cómputo del NDVI
 \\[0.4cm] }

\HRule \\[1.5cm]
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent
 \begin{flushright} \large
 \emph{Autor:}\\
 Smith \textsc{Jones}\\
 \emph{Tutores:} \\
 Pepe \textsc{Lez}\\
 Lore \textsc{Diez}
 \end{flushright}

{\large Junio 2015}

\end{titlepage}
    \end{document}
```

I obtain: [image: Looks fine to me]

But when I put the code on .tex document I obtain:

[image: Which doesn't look half as good as the previous one]

My document preamble code is:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
 \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{floatrow}
 \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section] {placeins}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[numbered]{mcode}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof,numbib]{tocbibind}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{10pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus  2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{8pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\usepackage{array}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage[round, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\linespread{1.1}
\begin{document}
 \begin{titlepage}...
```

Comment: You are using the `uarial` package and have set the main font as sans-serif (`\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}`)

Comment: @Astrinus Wanna make that an answer? :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Done.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading the `uarial` package, which replaces Computer Modern Sans Serif with URW Arial, and have set the main font as sans-serif (`\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}`), obviously the titlepage font get replaced.

If you want to have the titlepage in Computer Modern and the rest of the thesis in Arial, issue the `\renewcommand` after the `titlepage` environment ends.